# I'm trying to create a delete query for 2 tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-delete

I'm trying to devise a query to remove duplicates from 2 tables, these are CDUCUSTOMER and CDUINVOICE. The primary key is ID. The question also asks to ensure the query removes the duplicate data

Devise a delete query, which will eliminate duplicates for customer columns `ID`,
`CustomerLastName`, `CustomerFirstName` and invoice columns `Invoice_Date` and
`Invoice_No`.
◦   Ensure the query removes all duplicate data.

I have tried this

```
SELECT ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
FROM CDUCUSTOMER, CDUINVOICE
    (
  SELECT ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
  FROM CDUCUSTOMER
  UNION
  SELECT ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
  FROM CDUINVOICE
) TEMP
    WHERE TEMP.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM (
    SELECT ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRTSNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
    FROM CDUCUSTOMER
    UNION
    SELECT ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
    FROM CDUinvoice
  ) TEMP2
  GROUP BY ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRTSNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
);
```

im getting an error

```
sql error ora-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You need to provide the rule to determine which of duplicates should be retained and which should be deleted. It's not clear if you need to find duplicates in one table or in both tables and should deleted rows have any relation to the other table. In short: provide some sample data and desired output for it along with a description of the rules to get that result.

Comment: @marc_s, can you share the documentation by Oracle where "its use is discouraged" ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to use a function called `CDUINVOICE` but every row from 3 on is being passed as the parameter, or line 2 of your original query should just be `FROM` e.g.

```
SELECT ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
FROM (
  SELECT ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
  FROM CDUCUSTOMER
  UNION
  SELECT ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
  FROM CDUINVOICE
) TEMP
    WHERE TEMP.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM (
    SELECT ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRTSNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
    FROM CDUCUSTOMER
    UNION
    SELECT ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
    FROM CDUinvoice
  ) TEMP2
  GROUP BY ID, CUSTOMERLASTNAME, CUSTOMERFIRTSNAME, INVOICE__DATE, INVOICE_NO
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to delete duplicate rows from two tables.

If that's so, regarding the error code you got (**ORA**-01789) which says that you use Oracle, then: you can't delete rows from two tables using the same query.

I'm not sure what you meant to say by writing that code. It is invalid; there should be a comma, here:

```
FROM CDUCUSTOMER, CDUINVOICE         <-- here
    (
  SELECT ID,
```

Error you got suggests that there's `UNION` (yes, there are two of them), but `SELECT` statements returned different number of columns. That's not correct, at least not by looking at code you posted - all selects return 5 columns, so - regarding real error (missing comma) and error Oracle raised, I suspect that maybe you didn't post query you actually ran.

---

One way we use to remove duplicates is (one table at a time):

```
delete from cducustomer a
where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)
                 from cducustomer b
                 where a.id = b.id
                   and a.customerlastname = b.customerlastname
                   and a.customerfirstname = b.customerfirstname
                );
```

(you'd do the same with another table, performing joins on `invoice_date` and `invoice_no` columns).

If that's not what you want, could you post some sample data that illustrates the problem? Source data (which shows what you have now) and desired result (along with explanation why should that happen).

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, very helpful, I'll create 2 remove queries for the question. I was trying to find a query that would complete the task in 1. I spent way tooo long on it yesterday.

Comment: I could've put the wrong error up as I was trying different queries

Comment: just an unrelated question, I notice everyone does lowercase, while our lecturer insists on uppercase, what's generally used in the field?

Comment: Oracle doesn't care; it is just about **formatting**. GUI tools usually offer preferences which will apply e.g. UPPERCASE for keywords, lowercase for the rest of query (column and table names etc.), paint comments green etc. Query will work just fine even if you write everything in lowercase or uppercase, doesn't matter. I'm not sure what good would insisting on manual formatting do, if GUI tool does that in a matter of a keystroke.